# What are the options for queryOptions in the queryExecute function?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

The online documentation for the new ColdFusion 11 function queryExecute is here:

https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/QueryExecute

```
    QueryExecute(sql_str, queryParams, queryOptions);
```

Does anyone have documention for all of the options for "queryOptions" for this function?

The only options listed are in the examples in the documentation:

```
    result
    datasource
    fetchclientinfo
    cachename
```

I'm only sure of "datasource" and what it is for.  There must be others like "cachedwithin", "blockFactor", and the other options that can be used with <cfquery>.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the same as cfquery:

```
blockFactor = "block size"
cachedAfter = "date" 
cacheID = "ID"
cacheRegion = "region"
cachedWithin = "timespan"
dataSource = "data source name"
dbtype = "query"
debug = "yes|no"
fetchClientInfo = "yes|no"
maxRows = "number"
ormoptions = #orm options structure# 
password = "password"
result = "result name"
timeout = "seconds"
username = "user name"
```

If you want to know what these do, check the docs for cfquery. I assume you were asking for the list, not what each of these mean since they are already documented.

Comment: I've updated the `queryExecute()` docs to actually *say* this, and link back to the `<cfquery>` docs.

Comment: woot - thanks Adam. Hopefully I'm not breaking some rule by thanking you ;)

Comment: OH yeah. I imagined this non-sanctioned chatter will get us both seriously reprimanded by people no-one gives a toss about.